# If you save someone's life several times over, then have you only saved one life?

Tags: ethics

If you save someone's life several times over, then have you only saved one life? Likewise with groups of people, can you times it by the number of times you have done this or does the number of the people in the world put a limit on the value of your life saving powers?

Comment: This isn't really a philosophy question; it's a linguistic puzzle.

Comment: it's a question about the VALUE of doing so @DavidGudeman cf the question about "computation" which is merely a linguistic question

Comment: Regarding one person several times over, there's only one life that might have been lost, so only one saved.

Comment: maybe @JohnForkosh but then everyone dies eventually, so have you saved ZERO lives? my head hurts (i.e. am stupid haha)

Comment: I'm guessing @JohnForkosh that saving someone's life must be expressed with a time (I saved Margaret's life today) else the fact that at some time you do not means you did not. It seems then that the same thing isn't happening each time (in e.g. I saved Margaret's life today and yesterday). You need further assumptions (such as two different actions always having separate values) to get over the line, but some of those assumptions (such as my example, I think) may be intuitive, at least for the non-mystically inclined

Comment: What would be the point of such accounting?

Comment: however, especially if you want to talk about individuals (like Margaret, who keeps nearly dying @JohnForkosh !) then your judgment may be off if you think you have saved her on monday and she dies on tuesday instead, that it was merely postponed and not "saved". at least if she dies from the same cause

Comment: what's the point in any "accounting" @armand such are consequences (and i think consequences matter even in deontology, at least to an extent)

Comment: let's take a kantian example, if we must @armand kant and i are bartering over the price of some food. he says that there it is enough food to sustain the life of one person for 40 years, whereas i think it's sufficient to feed 40 people for a year. should the food have less value for kant than myself? i think that makes sense, apologies if not

Comment: Kant would probably say that the 39 people who won't be fed wouldn't consent to the 1 person/40 years plan, making it impossible to set as a universal rule, and therefore you should spread the food. But I see what you mean.

Comment: @DavidGudeman, how did ya know? 

Comment: We're it seems, despite my doubts in re obvious aspects of the *human condition*, making progress  in the relevant domains, but the man who likes popsicles isn't here! Too bad! Someone said something that if true would rectify this gross error.

Comment: People who work in Emergency Rooms would probably like to know the answer to this question. Then again, it might not matter to them. You can't save someone's life next time if you don't this time.

Answer (score 0):

This question needs a lot of clarification before it becomes answerable.

Let me guess at your train of thought. The answer to the first question is obviously only saved one life.

You are thinking about whether it is the number of times one saves life or the number of lives that one saves that counts, morally speaking. There is no simple answer to that; in the abstract, saving more lives rather than fewer is to be preferred, but that criterion is only helpful in specific situations, such as disaster relief or public health, where individual cases are not really relevant.

In a triage situation, one may be faced with a choice whether to save the life of someone (A) who has been saved one or more times in the past or (B) someone whose life has never been saved before. That difference would not normally be relevant. However, I think one could imagine circumstances when it might be, but the life-saving achievement of the decision-maker would always be irrelevant.

Then you take that measure and use that to measure the value of your life-saving power in general. However, a life-saving power is not really of value until it is exercised and exercised in the right way. If one walks away from every opportunity to exercise your power, it is not worth much. If one starts a fire in order to have the opportunity to increase one’s count of lives saved, it is worth still less.

The value of a life-saving power is only a potential. However, if one wanted to evaluate various training options in terms of their life-saving potential, then it would not be unreasonable to consider the number of lives saved; but only as one criterion amongst others. A public health campaigner might save more lives than a surgeon, but it doesn’t follow that the former is more valuable than the latter.

Everything about this question is complicated and depends on details of the situation in which the life is to be saved. That would be casuistry rather than philosophy, so I won’t try your patience any further.

“The trolley problem” was developed, and has been used in philosophy as a basis for discussing a wide range of ethical issues, which you may not be interested in. However, I have found the trolley thought experiment quite helpful in evaluating responses to various possible situations, and you may find it helpful. But I would be surprised if you could generate any general rules from it. See. [1.2: Introduction and Thought Experiments- The Trolley Problem - Humanities LibreTexts](https://human.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Philosophy/Critical_Reasoning_and_Writing_(Levin_et_al.)/01%3A_Introduction_to_Critical_Thinking%2C_Reasoning%2C_and_Logic/1.02%3A_Introduction_and_Thought_Experiments-_The_Trolley_Problem)